# JavaScript Inheritance: Calling a prototypal object in a HTML document - How to use Modules

Tags: javascript, inheritance, closures, prototype

I am struggling to produce a working JavaScript hierarchy. The basic example is as follows:

```
'use strict';
    
    const personFactory = (name) => ({
        talk() {
            console.log(`${name} says hello`);
        }
    });


'use strict';

const mammal = {
    isVertebrae: true
};

import * as mammal from './mammal.js';
import * as personFactory from './personFactory.js';
'use strict';

const personMammalFactory = (name) => (
    Object.assign(
        {},
        mammal,
        personFactory(name)
    )
);


<script type="module" src="~/js/modules/personMammalFactory.js"></script>


<script>

var factory = personMammalFactory('Brian');
factory.personFactory.talk();

</script>
```

personMammalFactory('Brian') throws a reference error: *Uncaught ReferenceError: personMammalFactory is not defined*

Please note that all three objects are in a separate file (personFactory.js, mammal.js, and personMammalFactory.js).

I cannot seem to call the personMammalFactory correctly into the HTML document. Can you please give me direction on what I might be doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, what you're building isn't a hierarchy, it's a set of mixins (which is fine!). That isn't the issue, it's just a terminology thing. :-)

There are two issues:

1. Everything is directly on the object, not on subobjects attached to it, so it wouldn't be `factory.personFactory.talk();`, it would be `factory.talk();` (except that what `personMammalFactory` returns isn't a factory, so I would call it something else, like `personMammal`).
2. Since your files are modules, they don't create any global variables;  the script code trying to use `personMammalfactory` is shown as a simple scripts, not a module, so it won't have access to anything in the modules without importing from them (unless they did something non-module-like such as creating globals on purpose, but there's no need). Separately, there are some issues with the exports and imports which we'll sort out in a moment.

...and then just a side note: modules are always in strict mode, so there's no need for `"use strict"` in them. (In files where you do use `"use strict";`, it has to be the first non-whitespace, non-comment in the file.)

Here's an example of fixing #1 with all the code shown in one script:

```js
'use strict';
    
const personFactory = (name) => ({
    talk() {
        console.log(`${name} says hello`);
    }
});

const mammal = {
    isVertebrate: true
//            ^−−−−−− (added missing t)
};

const personMammalFactory = (name) => (
    Object.assign(
        {},
        mammal,
        personFactory(name)
    )
);

const personMammal = personMammalFactory('Brian'); // "Brian says hello"
personMammal.talk();
console.log(personMammal.isVertebrate);            // true
```

To fix #2, you need to:

- Export `personMammalFactory`.
- Export `mammal`
- Import `mammal` and `personfactory` correctly in `personMammalFactory.js`
- Remove the `script` tag for `personMammalFactory.js` (it's not needed)
- Make your script where you're trying to use it a module that imports `personMammalFactory`, not just a simple script.

Doing all of that gives us this:

`personFactory.js`:

```
export const personFactory = (name) => ({ // *** Added `export`
    talk() {
        console.log(`${name} says hello`);
    }
});
```

`mammal.js`:

```
export const mammal = { // *** Added `export`
    isVertebrate: true
//            ^−−−−−− *** added missing t, FWIW
};
```

`personMammalFactory.js`:

```
import { mammal } from "./mammal.js";               // *** Added/modified
import { personFactory } from "./personFactory.js"; // *** Added/modified

export const personMammalFactory = (name) => (      // *** Added `export`
    Object.assign(
        {},
        mammal,
        personFactory(name)
    )
);

const personMammal = personMammalFactory('Brian'); // "Brian says hello"
personMammal.talk();
console.log(personMammal.isVertebrate);            // true
```

The main module script (type the `type`):

```
<script type="module">
import { personMammalFactory } from "./personMammalFactory.js";

const factory = personMammalFactory('Brian');
factory.talk();

</script>
```

The browser knows what other files to read from your server because it knows what the module hierarchy is, and the imports tell it where to find the files.

If you prefer, you could use default exports rather than named ones. (I strongly prefer named exports.)

`personFactory.js`:

```
export default const personFactory = (name) => ({ // *** Added `export default`
    talk() {
        console.log(`${name} says hello`);
    }
});
```

`mammal.js`:

```
export default const mammal = { // *** Added `export default`
    isVertebrate: true
//            ^−−−−−− *** added missing t, FWIW
};
```

`personMammalFactory.js`:

```
import mammal from "./mammal.js";                       // *** Added/modified
import personFactory from "./personFactory.js";         // *** Added/modified

export default const personMammalFactory = (name) => (  // *** Added `export`
    Object.assign(
        {},
        mammal,
        personFactory(name)
    )
);

const personMammal = personMammalFactory('Brian'); // "Brian says hello"
personMammal.talk();
console.log(personMammal.isVertebrate);            // true
```

The main module script (type the `type`):

```
<script type="module">
import personMammalFactory from "./personMammalFactory.js";

const factory = personMammalFactory('Brian');
factory.talk();

</script>
```

---

**If** you wanted to do a hierarchy, in JavaScript those are done via the prototype chain, either directly or indirectly through constructor functions. Given your example, I suspect you'd be more comfortable doing it directly. To do that, you'd use `Object.create` and pass in the object that should be the prototype; the return value is an object that uses the object you passed in as a prototype:

```
const object = Object.create(prototyepObject);
```

So for instance, here's a `personMammalFactory` that creates objects that use `mammal` as their prototype:

```js
"use strict";

const personFactory = (name) => ({
    talk() {
        console.log(`${name} says hello`);
    }
});

const mammal = {
    isVertebrate: true
//            ^−−−−−− (added missing t)
};

const personMammalFactory = (name) => (
    Object.assign(
        Object.create(mammal),          // *** The key difference
        personFactory(name)
    )
);

const personMammal = personMammalFactory("Brian");
personMammal.talk();                    // "Brian says hello"
console.log(personMammal.isVertebrate); // true
```

(There is one "gotcha" in the above: If you used `super` within `talk`, it would refer to `Object.prototype`, not `mammal`. In something like the above I'd probably avoid making `talk` an actual method by using `talk: () => { /*...*/ }` or something rather than `talk() { /* ... */ }`, so it doesn't have access to `super`.)

---

Or if you wanted, you could go down the path of constructor functions, which is most conveniently done with the `class` syntax. But that doesn't look like it suits what you're doing.

Comment: This is great info. However, it did not solve my problem. I still have the reference error...

Comment: @JoshuaTrimm - Ah, I see the second problem. Updating now. :-)

Comment: @JoshuaTrimm - Okay, all updated now. I'd overlooked that there were some module issues as well. :-) (FWIW, I go into modules in some depth in Chapter 13 of my new book; links in my profile if you're interested.)

Answer (score 0):

T.J Crowder provided essential information for me to solve this problem. The problem seemed to be how FireFox was interpreting the exports and imports. Exports and imports are handled differently based upon your browser.

As ussual, the fix was simple but hard to find: You must use *export default { nameObject }* AFTER defining the *const* of a *base object*. If the *export* is put before the *const* Firefox produces a MIME type error with no hints to what is causing the issue (see Code Figure 1.0). The second issue was using JavaScript's relative path syntax correctly in the *import*. As mentioned in *"[Relative paths from the root in javascript](https://coderwall.com/p/8nhqeg/relative-paths-from-the-root-in-javascript)"*, using the backslash (see Code Figure 1.3) will get the relative root path. I did not, however, use the relative position in the JS files, but only in the HTML file import  (see Code Figure 1.2).

*Note: each object is a separate file (mammal.js, personFactory.js, and personMammalFactory.js).*

**Incorrect Export Method:** 1.0

```
    export default const mammal = {
    isVertebrae: true
};
```

**Correct Export Method:** 1.1

```
const mammal = {
    isVertebrae: true
};

export default { mammal };
```

**Correct Import Inheritance Structure:** 1.2

```
import mammal from './mammal.js';
import personFactory from './personFactory.js';



export const personMammalFactory = (name) => (
    Object.assign(
        {},
        mammal,
        personFactory(name)
    )
);
```

**HTML File Import:** 1.3

```
// Declare this script a module. 
     <script type="module">

            // Note the relative path using the backslash and the use of brackets. By using this this is not need for and src include.
            import { personMammalFactory } from '/js/modules/personMammalFactory.js';
    
            
            // Inheritance is now happy :-) 
            const factory = personMammalFactory('Brian');
            
            console.log(factory);
    
            factory.talk();
    </scrip>
```

**Record of Correct Output:** 1.4
[image]